# Python rows of string to list of rows

Tags: python, list

I need help on formating rows of string:

```
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
1026,1026 N MADISON ST
```

to list such as:

```
['SNUMBER', 'FULL_ADDRE']
['822', '822 E ASH AVE']
['1012', '1012 BRIAR CREEK RD']
['1026', '1026 N MADISON ST']

list(self.new_dbf) # breaks this down to a million peaces
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a CSV?

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: You are most likely looking for [`string.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split), or if you need more sophisticated parsing, the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

txt='''\
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
1026,1026 N MADISON ST'''


for line in csv.reader(txt.splitlines()):
    print line
```

Prints:

```
['SNUMBER', 'FULL_ADDRE']
['822', '822 E ASH AVE']
['1012', '1012 BRIAR CREEK RD']
['1026', '1026 N MADISON ST']
```

Comment: yes I'm parsing a CSV file object.  thanks dawg

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input format, `string.split(',')` will probably work for you. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
text = """SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
1026,1026 N MADISON ST
"""
p=functools.partial(str.split,sep=",")
matrix1 = map(p,text.splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lines = open('addresses').readlines() 
>>> [ line.strip().split(',', 1) for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = '''SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
1026,1026 N MADISON ST'''
>>> [a.split(',') for a in a.split('\n')]
[['SNUMBER', 'FULL_ADDRE'], ['822', '822 E ASH AVE'], ['1012', '1012 BRIAR CREEK RD'], ['1026', '1026 N MADISON ST']]
```